# Teradata SQL Assistant: Alternatives {on Windows}

Tags: teradata

Are there alternatives to Teradata SQL Assistant {on windows}, possibly freeware?
[Heidi](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heidisql.com%2Fforum.php%3Ft%3D13798&ei=qwrnVLmrKdPqaKjggHg&usg=AFQjCNHioDfoksJ9ZvJsTL332Nk_DaxOFg&sig2=dDT-LjYpZw5065yKrXeLTQ&bvm=bv.86475890,d.d2s) is great but it does not support Teradata.
What are the pros and cons of the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata Studio and Studio Express are the long term replacements for SQL Assistant from Teradata. They are developed around an Eclipse based IDE and are available to download from [Teradata Developer Exchange](http://developer.teradata.com/tools).

Answer (score 1):

[Database .NET](http://fishcodelib.com/Database.htm) is a **Free** universal database manager for **Windows All**, 
It supports most popular databases, including **Teradata database**.

Comment: Looks good but it is "provided as freeware for personal and non-profit use"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the reason is price,  but the latest version of SQL Assistant is downloadable free from Teradata's website:

http://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-studio

You don't have to install everything, just pick and choose what you want.